# NSDictionary memory leak after tring to overwrite content

Tags: ipad, memory

Trying to track down a memory leak. I have it traced to a synthesized NSDictionary that is used to store plist data read in from the documents folder on startup. The first time it runs, no leaks. But later in the app I make a web call that overwrites the NSDictonary object and thats where I see the leak.

The update works well, but in instruments, I am see a leak at the point of overwriting the NSDictionary.

I've tried the standard release and nil before setting the synthesized NSDictionary to the new content. Not sure what to try next.

Usually find the answer I am looking for right away here. But this ones stumping me.

```
NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];


Hubplist = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization
                                      propertyListWithData:plistXML
                                      options:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                      format:&format
                                      error:NULL];
```

Comment: no, Not using ARC. I do have a retain on the data, and that seems to be working across the life of the app (which it needs to).

Comment: In that case your code snippet shows nothing useful to your question :)

Answer (score 0):

if you have retained or allocated Hubplist anywhere you need to release it before overriding it.

```
NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];

[Hubplist release];
Hubplist = nil;
Hubplist = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization
                                      propertyListWithData:plistXML
                                      options:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                      format:&format
                                      error:NULL];
// Also make sure to retain it if needed
[Hubplist retain];
```